# How do I change private network to public network in windows 10 pro technical preview

Tags: windows, windows-10-preview

Whenever I connect my LAN wire to my system, Windows 10 automatically detects it and connect to it as **Private Network**. How would I change it to **public network** since most of my applications are set to access internet in **public network** only.

Comment: I think there may be some conceptual issue here… a public network is an inherently unsafe one, like an internet cafe or Starbucks. Your in-house network is, in fact, a private network & you should organise your apps' connectivity accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Windows 10, but for Windows 8 you go into PC Settings then into Network > Connections and then turn Find Devices and content to off. This should turn your network into a public one.

You can also do this via Windows Powershell. Make sure to start it elevated (Run as Administrator)

1. Run Get-NetConnectionProfile command to find the list of all connected interfaces. Note the interface ID of the connection that you are trying to change.
2. Run Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex [Interface ID] -NetworkCategory Public

Comment: We tried several other methods and THIS one is the only that worked. The problem with some instructions is about the difference in "Name" and "InterfaceAliase". Thank you!!!